# Validation annotation for indicating that a checkbox is checked

Tags: java, forms, validation, spring-mvc

I have a custom object that represents my form like:

```
public class RegisterForm {

    @NotNull(message = "Account name cannot be empty.")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50, message = "Account name must be between 3 and 50 characters long.")
    private String accountName;


    private boolean termsConditions;
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
public ModelAndView create(@Valid AccountForm accountForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {

}
```

So I added the boolean termsConditions that will be for a checkbox on the form.

**What is the annotation I should use to ensure this value is true?** i.e the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be [`javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/AssertTrue.html). From JavaDoc:

> The annotated element must be true. Supported types are boolean and Boolean